# Need Help to understand the do while loop in details

Tags: c++

Please do not try to modify the code. This code works fine.I took it from a book.I just need some help to understand the behavior of the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void suffle2(int[][13]);
int main(){
  int deck[4][13] = { 0 };
  srand(time(0));
  suffle2(deck);

  return 0;
}
void suffle2(int d[4][13])
{
   int row, column;
   for (int card = 1; card <= 20; card++)
   {

     do{

        row = rand() % 4;
        column = rand() % 13;
        cout << "d[" << row << "]" << "[" << column << "]" << "=" << d[row][column]<<endl;
       } while (d[row][column] != 0);       
      d[row][column] = card;
      cout << "d[" << row << "]" << "[" << column << "]" << "=" << d[row][column] <<endl;
   }
}
```

Both `cout << "d[" << row << "]" << "[" << column << "]" << "=" << d[row][column] <<endl;`
I code to understand the behavior.My question is:
deck[4][13] has initialized to 0.So the while loop should not work cause it should always 
find d[row][column] == 0 but it is not..it is working fine.

second question is,suppose the output is following:

```
d[0][4]=0
d[0][4]=1
d[2][4]=0
d[2][4]=2
d[1][12]=0
d[1][12]=3--------duplicate
d[3][11]=0
d[3][11]=4
d[0][6]=0
d[0][6]=5
d[1][12]=3--------duplicate
d[1][11]=0
d[1][11]=6
d[0][7]=0
d[0][7]=7<--------------------duplicate
d[1][6]=0
d[1][6]=8
d[0][6]=5
d[0][11]=0
d[0][11]=9
d[2][11]=0
d[2][11]=10
d[3][11]=4
d[3][2]=0
d[3][2]=11
d[2][11]=10
d[1][10]=0
d[1][10]=12
d[1][6]=8
d[0][9]=0
d[0][9]=13
d[0][1]=0
d[0][1]=14
d[3][4]=0
d[3][4]=15
d[0][7]=7 <---------------------duplicate
d[0][2]=0
d[0][2]=16
d[0][3]=0
d[0][3]=17
d[2][11]=10
d[0][5]=0
d[0][5]=18
d[0][9]=13
d[0][10]=0
d[0][10]=19
d[1][6]=8
d[1][7]=0
d[1][7]=20
Press any key to continue . . .
```

In the for loop the card value is incremental but when the duplicate card value is found for the same index of array, it is taking the very first value for that index.Why it is not changing the increment value?Please help me to understand the code.

Comment: Have you tried seeding the generator with a fixed number (so that you always get the same sequence) and then stepping through the code in a debugger? That would probably tell you how it works.

Comment: If you guys don't like to help don't bother to visit this site.I am really surprised how ignorant you guys are.Do you really feel superior by giving -1 but helping a new coder?

Comment: this attitude is uncalled for. I didn't downvote you, but your question does not really show any research effort (which is a valid reason for downvoting). That's what my earlier comment was about - step through the code, either with a debugger or perhaps using pen & paper; if it's still unclear, say in the question that you have done so and ask about specific aspects of the flow which are unclear.

Comment: If it took you 32 minutes to figure out the code (the time between your question and that comment), you should not have asked it in the first place. Stack Overflow expects you to put *serious effort* into solving a problem yourself before asking others to spend their **free time** on **your** problem.

Comment: I am not expert coder like you guys may be.I spent 3 hours then I took the chunk of this code from the actual code which is over 300 lines then I put it here so that it becomes easier for experts to help me.

Comment: I did not want to mean that but did you see how the user Gall helped a new coder?This is call help.I think next time everyone should remember that before putting -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, all values of deck are 0 at the beginning and the loop works because the `do{}while(condition);` is executing at least once before checking `condition`. The loop is looking here for the first uninitialized card.

Duplicate output is just what the loop is currently checking, it finds an initialized card so it keeps looking for an uninitialized one (this is the first cout).

Comment: Thanks man . I really appreciate your help..I just figured it out. At least you are not among those who comes here to insult people

Comment: @user830664 You shouldn't feel insulted by the SO site mechanics. It's nothing personal. Take on Angew's advice. SO isn't a discussion forum but purposed as a FAQ like Q&A site. This requires valid questions in 1st place.